# Indentation of First Paragraphs

Tags: indentation

Sorry for this silly question, but why does LaTeX indent the very beginning paragraph?

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}

Here \LaTeX{} indents this paragraph.

\end{abstract}

It does this one too. \LaTeX{} does not indent first paragraphs, but why these two?

\section{TEXT}

This one is not indented as usual.

\end{document}
```

What is the internal LaTeX standard?

Comment: At least in academic texts is not usual start a text without a heading, so for this special case the best is simply use `\noident`. Also you can change `\parindent` everywhere (e.g. `\setlength\parindent{0pt}` foo\par `\setlength\parindent{1em}` ...).  As the answer pointed `\parindent` can be modified by document class, but also by packages (`parskip`, `babel`) but you actually showed the "standard" of the standard `article`: indent always except after a header,  ... or a `itemize` list  not ended by blank line (or an `enumerate` list,  but not in a  raw `list`  environment).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Paragraph indentation is suppressed after section headings and not anywhere else by default. Some document class may define `abstract` to suppress indentation some may not, it is a choice of that class author. LaTeX itself (in the format) does not define an `abstract` environment at all so there can be no built in default here.